# WPF - Return image from converter using pack URI

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, ivalueconverter

I would like to create a WPF converter to return a certain image depending on a boolean value.

I have so far got the following code:

```
 return (bool) value
                   ? new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,MyApp.ApplicationResources;component/Resources/image1.png", UriKind.Absolute))
                   : new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,MyApp.ApplicationResources;component/Resources/image2.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

However this gives me the exception

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred 
Message=The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

The Images are in a referenced Assembly of : MyApp.ApplicationResources in a folder "Resources" and both are set to Content Type: Resource.

If I use the same URI in source property of an image in xaml it works fine!

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: did you try without the UriKind.Absolute? I use the exact same syntax and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are missing a `/` in your `Uri`:

```
return (bool) value
               ? new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp.ApplicationResources;component/Resources/image1.png", UriKind.Absolute))
               : new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp.ApplicationResources;component/Resources/image2.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```